# How do I subtract two dates that are in rows (not given in the query) Mysql

Tags: mysql, date

Say you're designing a system for a library and you want two dates to be subtracted - the checkout date and the checkin date.  I have a file with both of these dates along with the video id and customer id.  I also want to sort by 7 or more days (the book is due today or past due).

I had something like this, which worked up until the date parts:

```
SELECT customers.first_name, customers.last_name, video_checkout.checkout_date, 
video_checkout.checkin_date FROM video_rental, customers, video_checkout 
WHERE video_checkout.checkout_date - video_checkout.checkin_date >= 7;
```

So I decided to try a date_sum and TIMESTAMPDIFF, but after 2 hours of Googling, it doesn't seem that date_sums or TIMESTAMPDIFFS support subtracting two dates from tables.

Is there anyway to subtract dates that are in tables?  Can I create a query that will return the subtracted dates, video id and customer id for many entries?

Using Mysql Workbench 6.3.4

The dates are in the video checkout file like this:

```
DELETE FROM video_checkout;

INSERT INTO video_checkout VALUES (
'1',
'1',
'2015-08-20',
'2015-08-30'
);

INSERT INTO video_checkout VALUES (
'1',
'5',
'2015-08-19',
'2015-08-29'
);
```

In the end I want it to look something like this:

> Firstname | Lastname | Due date

Comment: Wouldn't the due date be the checkout_date plus a number of days rather than the difference between it and the checkin_date (the date they returned it)?  Because I would think if the checkin_date is filled in it means they brought it back and is no longer due.

Comment: No the checkout date is the date that it is due.  It doesn't mean that it was returned yet.  But that is another way to think about it.

Comment: So how do you know if the book has been returned yet or not?  If the checkin_date is when it is due, you actually want to do a datediff to today to see if it is in the past, but you would also need a condition to check if it has been returned or not.  I think you want a checkout_date, due_date & checkin_date (checkin_date will be null if it has not yet been returned)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
SELECT customers.first_name, customers.last_name, video_checkout.checkout_date, 
video_checkout.checkin_date FROM video_rental, customers, video_checkout 
WHERE DATEDIFF (video_checkout.checkout_date, video_checkout.checkin_date) >= 7;
```

Comment: Error Code: 1582. Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF' 0.000 sec

Comment: Yeah, that's because it should be DATEDIFF (video_checkout.checkout_date, video_checkout.checkin_date)  Comma instead of a minus sign.  I've corrected Rohit's code